# Hash and date of the local commit being used?

Tags: git, hash

I'm having trouble figuring out the easiest way to get the hash and date of the local commit being used.

I can use `rev-parse` to get a hash, but I have no idea what the hash corresponds to because Git's workflows are not as simple as "this is a copy of the server's files" (assuming no local changes):

```
git rev-parse HEAD
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I take the hash `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and plug it into `git log`, I get countless entries back rather than information on the hash in question:

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
Author: ...
Date: ...
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
Author: ...
Date: ...
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
Author: ...
Date: ...
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
Author: ...
Date: ...
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
Author: ...
Date: ...
...
```

I want the information for reporting during self tests. Folks send me the text file with an occasional failure, and I'm finding I need more information because they may not be using the latest sources.

How do I determine the hash and date of the local commit that's being tested?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're just interested in the most recent commit, then why not `git show`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII - Well, I need to know what's being tested, and not what the latest commit is at GitHub.

Comment: I mean instead of plugging the hash into git log, try plugging it into git show, this will give you all the info about that specific commit.

Comment: Sounds like a procedural issue, not a git question. Change git with something else and the same problem remains, how do you know what they are testing with? Well, you have to establish some kind of procedure that ensures that when test results are produced, you know from which version of the code they were run from. You might create a script that gets the code and puts into a log the version of the code used and then appends into that log the test results, so the two pieces of info travel together.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `git log`, not `git rev-parse`. The following command will output information about the currently checked out commit (no diff, just metadata):

```
git log -1
```

For automated processing, you might prefer a single line with only the commit hash and author date. Adjust the format to your liking:

```
git log -1 --format="%h %ad" --date=short
```